# algorithm2e: Exclude functions from \listofalgorithms

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithm2e

I'm using the package `algorithm2e` and create a list of algorithms with `\listofalgorithms`. My problem is that not only the algorithms (*algorithm*), but also the functions (*function*) are displayed in the list of algorithms.

Is it somehow possible that the function `func()` (see the following example) is not shown in the list of algorithms?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 

\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage[ruled,algosection,algo2e]{algorithm2e} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{algorithm} 
\caption{Foo bar} 
 ... 
\end{algorithm} 

\begin{function} 
\caption{func()} 
... 
\end{function} 

\newpage 
\renewcommand*{\listalgorithmname}{Algorithmenverzeichnis} 
\listofalgorithms 
\clearpage 

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is descriped in the documentation at page 17:

> label now puts the name (the text before the braces in the caption)
>   of the procedure or function as reference (not the number like a
>   classic algorithm environment).

You can change it by redefining some internals of the package:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\algocf@caption@proc#1[#2]#3{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@nokwfunc}}{\relax}{%
    \SetKwFunction{\algocf@captname#3@}{\algocf@captname#3@}%
  }%
  % we tell hyperref to use algocfproc as category and to take the appropriate ref.
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@func}}{\def\@proc@func{algocffunc}}{\def\@proc@func{algocfproc}}%
  \@ifundefined{hyper@refstepcounter}{\relax}{% if hyper@refstepcounter undefind, no hyperref, else...
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@procnumbered}}{% 
      \expandafter\def\csname theH\@proc@func\endcsname{\algocf@captname#3@}%if procnumbered, take \thealgocf as ref
    }{%
      \expandafter\def\csname theH\@proc@func\endcsname{\algocf@captname#3@}%else take procedure or function name
    }%
    \hyper@refstepcounter{\@proc@func}%
  }%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@procnumbered}}{\relax}{%
    \addtocounter{algocf}{-1}% \caption do a refstepcounter, so we restore the precedent value
    \gdef\@currentlabel{\algocf@captname#3@}% let the label be the name of the function, not the counter
  }%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\algocf@captparam#2@}{\arg@e}}{% if no paramater, we remove the ()
    \algocf@latexcaption{#1}[\algocf@captname#2@]{#3}%
  }{%                                                 else we give the complete name
    \algocf@latexcaption{#1}[#2]{#3}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother
```

I removed the following statement:

```
\algocf@procname\nobreakspace
```