# Exclude functions and procedures completely from list of algorithms in algorithm2e

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithm2e

I'm referring to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106016/45570) answer of the question on 'how to exclude functions from \listofalgorithms in algorithm2e'. The solution provided in the answer just omits the word `function` within the list of algorithms, but still prints the function name without a number (the number is replaced by a `-`).

I would like to completely remove the entries for all functions and procedures from the list of algorithms. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal example below uses code from the answer to [`algorithm2e`: Exclude functions from `\listofalgorithms`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106013/5764) with the addition of `\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}` in the appropriate location where contents is written to the List of Algorithms:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 

\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage[ruled,algosection,algo2e]{algorithm2e} 

\makeatletter
\long\def\algocf@caption@proc#1[#2]#3{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@nokwfunc}}{\relax}{%
    \SetKwFunction{\algocf@captname#3@}{\algocf@captname#3@}%
  }%
  % we tell hyperref to use algocfproc as category and to take the appropriate ref.
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@func}}{\def\@proc@func{algocffunc}}{\def\@proc@func{algocfproc}}%
  \@ifundefined{hyper@refstepcounter}{\relax}{% if hyper@refstepcounter undefind, no hyperref, else...
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@procnumbered}}{% 
      \expandafter\def\csname theH\@proc@func\endcsname{\algocf@captname#3@}%if procnumbered, take \thealgocf as ref
    }{%
      \expandafter\def\csname theH\@proc@func\endcsname{\algocf@captname#3@}%else take procedure or function name
    }%
    \hyper@refstepcounter{\@proc@func}%
  }%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@procnumbered}}{\relax}{%
    \addtocounter{algocf}{-1}% \caption do a refstepcounter, so we restore the precedent value
    \gdef\@currentlabel{\algocf@captname#3@}% let the label be the name of the function, not the counter
  }%
  \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}% Remove placement of content
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\algocf@captparam#2@}{\arg@e}}{% if no paramater, we remove the ()
    \algocf@latexcaption{#1}[\algocf@captname#2@]{#3}%
  }{%                                                 else we give the complete name
    \algocf@latexcaption{#1}[#2]{#3}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

\begin{function} 
\caption{func()} 
... 
\end{function} 

\begin{algorithm} 
\caption{Foo bar} 
 ... 
\end{algorithm} 

\newpage 
\renewcommand*{\listalgorithmname}{Algorithmenverzeichnis} 
\listofalgorithms 
\clearpage 

\end{document}
```